# Invoke from another class, a function from another function in an exported class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I'm running into issues with below scenario, function foo is not invoked as part of click event on Button in class B, how can I achieve this? 
(I know the title sucks, please feel free to change it)

```js
A.js
----

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import B from './B';


class A extends Component {

  foo = () => {
    console.log("called foo");
    /* some code */
  }
  
  bar = () => {
    console.log("called bar");
    /* some more code */
    this.foo();
  }
  
  
  render() {
    return (<B bar={this.bar} />);
  }

}

B.js
----

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class B extends Component {

  render() {
    return (<button onClick={() => this.props.bar()} />);    
  }

}
```

Comment: class B doesn't have a `foo` method

Comment: please fix your code ... the trailing `this.foo(); }

}` makes no sense where it is

Comment: There's no Button and `return` in render, the rest should work as expected,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lqn9ux . The question doesn't contain a problem that could be solved.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, I missed to add return statement, but the question is how can I ensure foo is invoked as part of button click in component B via call to bar in onclick event?

Comment: @JaromandaX , yes but I want to invoke foo from A as part of onclick event calling bar

Comment: @estus The problem is I don't see line "called foo" being printed, as part of onclick event on button in B (which should happen as I am registering bar as onclick handler and bar calls foo)

Comment: It's clearly seen in a demo above, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lqn9ux . Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. Otherwise the question is considered off-topic and can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The render method should use return syntax to return JSX elements. Add return as suggested below to both the components so that they work as you wanted

A.js

```
render() {
    return(<div><B bar={this.bar} /></div>)
}
```

B.js

```
render() {
    return(<div><Button onClick={() => this.props.bar()} /> </div>)
 }
```

Please note if you are using latest React version then use React.Fragment in place of div otherwise div is fine

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, I missed to add return statement, but the question is how can I ensure foo is invoked as part of button click in component B  via call to bar in onclick event?